# How to efficiently combine two (or more) associative arrays with common keys

Tags: php, python, arrays, merge

More generally, let's say we have two lists of different lengths with one common attribute:

```
list1: {
         {"orderID":1234, "FirstName":"shaheeb", "LastName":"roshan"},
         {"orderID":9183, "FirstName":"robert", "LastName":"gibbons"},
         {"orderID":2321, "FirstName":"chester"},
       }
list2: {
         {"orderID":1234, "cell":"555-555-5555", "email":"roshan@fake.com"},
         {"orderID":2321, "email":"chester@fake.com"},
       }
```

I would like these combined into:

```
list3: {
         {"orderID":1234, "FirstName":"shaheeb", "LastName":"roshan", "cell":"555-555-5555", "email":"roshan@fake.com"},
         {"orderID":9183, "FirstName":"robert", "LastName":"gibbons"},
         {"orderID":2321, "FirstName":"chester", "email":"chester@fake.com"},
       }
```

I'm primarily a PHP developer, and I came up with the following:

```
function mergeArrays($a1, $a2) {
    $larger = (count($a1) > count($a2)) ? $a1 : $a2;
    $smaller = ($larger == $a1) ? $a2 : $a1;
    $combinedArray = array();
    foreach ($larger AS $key=>$largerSet) {
        $combinedRow = array();
        if (isset ($smaller[$key]) ) {
            $combinedRow = $largerSet + $smaller[$key];
            $combinedArray[$key] = $combinedRow;
        }else {
            $combinedArray[$key] = $largerSet;
        }
    }
    return ($combinedArray);
}
```

If tested with the following:

```
$array1 = array("12345"=>array("OrderID"=>12345, "Apt"=>"blue"));
$array2 = array(
                "12345"=>array("OrderID"=>12345, "AnotherCol"=>"Goons", "furtherColumns"=>"More Data"),
                "13433"=>array("OrderID"=>32544, "Yellow"=>"Submarine")
            );
```

The mergeArrays($array1, $array2) outputs the following:

```
array(2) {
  [12345]=>
  array(4) {
    ["OrderID"]=>
    int(12345)
    ["AnotherCol"]=>
    string(5) "Goons"
    ["furtherColumns"]=>
    string(9) "More Data"
    ["Apt"]=>
    string(4) "blue"
  }
  [13433]=>
  array(2) {
    ["OrderID"]=>
    int(32544)
    ["Yellow"]=>
    string(9) "Submarine"
  }
}
```

But I just don't feel like this is the most elegant solution.  For example, I should be able to combine n number of arrays.  Not really sure how I would accomplish that.  Also, just looking at that bit of code, I'm fairly certain there are far more effective ways to accomplish this requirement.

As a learning point, I am curious whether python experts would take this opportunity to show up us PHP folk :).  For that matter, I am curious whether Excel/VBA can even handle this.  That is where I started trying to solve this problem with the thought that "surely excel can handle lists!".

I am fully aware that there are many many variations of this question around SO.  I have looked at several of these, and still felt that I should try my version out here.

Your thoughts are most appreciated.

Thank you!

SR

Comment: Are you looking for a PHP solution or a Python solution? I think Python, right?

Comment: Either 1) make language agnostic (e.g. "theory of combining", which is boring) or 2) leave only one language tag in :-) The algorithm is likely too complicated with the larger/smaller stuff. What is really happening is a "join" on a certain property (or set of properties) which is a two-part operation (detection -- finding join-able values -- and merging).

Answer (score 4):

For a general solution in Python, for any number of lists:

```
orders = defaultdict(dict)
for order_list in order_lists:
    for order in order_list:
        orders[order['orderID']].update(order)
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/jEFQC)

Comment: As a note, this will work with Python 2.7 (I believe) or higher -- +1 for a *very* nice answer!

Comment: I've coded up a more generic form of this in my answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

A generic solution that can merge any number of dicts (or a list of dicts - if you have more than one list, just add them together before calling the function):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_dicts_by_key(key, *dicts):
    return reduce(lambda acc,val: acc[val[key]].update(val) or acc,
                  dicts,
                  defaultdict(dict))
```

---

Call like so:

```
merge_dicts_by_key('orderId', dict1, dict2, dict3)
```

or, if you have lists of dicts:

```
merge_dicts_by_key('orderId', *list_of_dicts)
merge_dicts_by_key('orderId', *(list1 + list2))
```

Comment: Your `lambda` and`dicts` are swapped; but I put them in the correct positions, and this still doesn't work for me. I am mystified as to why.

Comment: Whoops. Fixed the order there. How were you invoking it?

Comment: Found the issue. Forgot that `x.update(y)` doesn't actually return x when it's done, and reduce expects the function to return the result rather than modifying the accumulator in-place. Adding the `or acc` to the end of the lambda fixed it, since update() returns None and thus the `or` will always evaluate to the newly-updated `acc`.

Comment: Ah, excellent. +1 then for a terse and general solution. (Actually I upvoted it before testing :) )

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always replace your function with [`array_merge_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php).